# Changing default text input on Nexus 7 Ubuntu to bluetooth keyboard

Tags: bluetooth, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I was curious if it was possible to use a Logitech bluetooth keyboard for android 4.0+ with Ubuntu on Nexus 7?

I was able to connect the keyboard regularly with the GUI, the pin worked, so I would assume it is a matter of changing the default text input. I searched all of the settings I could find without finding any such option.

Any help would be appreciated, if this is not possible feel free to say so and close this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, bluetooth is not quite working on the image yet, so this won't be possible yet.

Here's the bug:
[#1070770 bluetoothd dies with glibc malloc memory corruption when used with brcm_patchram](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-nexus7/+bug/1070770)